# Is there a facility for testing MFA within IPP AggCatServices?

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, customer-account-data-api

I've run into a snag with MFA when trying to add accounts.  The code isn't so much the problem, but the ability to test various MFA scenarios?

Does Intuit provide a test bank in the institutions list that exercises the possible MFA scenarios?

I really don't want to resort to live-testing other folks bank accounts that use MFA, (mine doesn't).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0020_customeraccountdata/customer_account_data_api/testing_calls_to_the_api

CCBank - 100000

This also includes MFA.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Intuit has setup a dummy FI for testing purpose.

API Doc - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0020_customeraccountdata/customer_account_data_api/0020_api_documentation/0020_discoverandaddaccounts

Please refer this page - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0020_customeraccountdata/customer_account_data_api/testing_calls_to_the_api

Thanks